# wpf applying datatemplates in code-behind

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I'm creating a custom ItemsControl that contains a grid for display whatever. I'd like the user to be able to use datatemplates for displaying that whatever, but how do I go about doing that?

I know how to create the templates, but I'm not sure how to go about applying a template such that the items are located properly within the grid (my code) and each item is displayed as the user wants (via the datatemplate).

-- edit --

There appears to be a little confusion as to what I'm asking. Imagine I wanted to create my own ListView from scratch using a Grid for the layout (that's not what I'm actually doing, but as an example ... ). Given a DataTemplate from the user, how do I use that to ensure the elements inside each grid cell are displayed according to the template?

Comment: Use DataTemplateSelector to select template.

Comment: Don't do code behind stuff. Learn WPF properly and use proper XAML and DataBinding

Comment: @HighCore Please provide a more useful comment. I've edited my question to provide a little more clarification of what I'm doing. If you can show me how to do that via XAML, then great. If I already knew how to do that I wouldn't be here asking the question.

Comment: @ryan0270 I can't provide a full answer because I'm busy right now. And there are literally hundreds of answers of mine explaining how to use WPF properly as opposed to code behind stuff (which I could use to mark your question as duplicate and close it). Search my answer history or google "stackoverflow highcore delete all your code" and you'll get it.

Comment: @HighCore and other down-voters/close-mongers, please take a moment to try to understand the question instead of making assumptions based on the OP's title.

Comment: Let's try to be a helpful community first and sticklers second. As we know, adding properties to custom controls means working in the code-behind; the OP is trying to understand how all the pieces then get wired up together. If you find a truly relevant duplicate question with a decent answer, please post a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your control can expose its own property/properties, which you declare in your code-behind.
If you need a single `DataTemplate`, then you can expose a property of type `DataTemplate`. When a user declares your control type in XAML, she can provide the template:

```
<ns:YourControl>
    <ns:YourControl.DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            …
        </DataTemplate>
    </ns:YourControl.DataTemplate>
</ns:YourControl>
```

In your own control, you consume this by binding to the `DataTemplate` property. Be sure to reference the control itself in your `Binding`, rather than the `DataContext`. You'll probably want a default `DataTemplate` or throw a useful `Exception` in the event that the user does not specify a `DataTemplate`.

You can give the user some additional flexibility if you expose a property of type `DataTemplateSelector` and then apply that to your items, if the data types are disparate or the user is likely to want different templates under different circumstances.

#### Example

MyControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyControl"
             x:Name="ThisControl">
    <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{Binding ItemTemplate, ElementName=ThisControl}" />
</UserControl>
```

MyControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty 
        = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof (DataTemplate), 
        typeof (MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(DataTemplate)));

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate) GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    // Other dependency properties (ItemsSource, SelectedItem, etc.)
}
```

The consumer:

```
<Grid>
    <ns:MyControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
        <ns:MyControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="2"
                        BorderBrush="Black">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="DarkGray"
                               Text="{Binding Name}"
                               Margin="4" />
               </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ns:MyControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ns:MyControl>
</Grid>
```

#### Update

Okay, here is a working example of populating the `Grid` and using the `DataTemplate`.

`MyControl` exposes a property, `ItemsSource`, which allows the consumer to bind to a collection in her view-model. `MyControl` also exposes a property, `ItemTemplate`, which allows a consumer to specify how to display those items (again, you could also allow the user to specify a `DataTemplateSelector`).

In the code-behind, when the source collection changes, we

1. create a `ColumnDefinition` for each item,
2. wrap each item inside another class that exposes `Row` and `Column` properties, and
3. add each wrapped item to a private collection, which is what we actually bind to in our control.

First, the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="ThisControl"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding BindableItems, ElementName=ThisControl, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}" />
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{Binding ItemTemplate, ElementName=ThisControl}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

And the code-behind:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
  public partial class MyControl : UserControl
  {
    public MyControl()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "ItemsSource", typeof (IEnumerable), typeof (MyControl), 
      new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable), OnItemsSourceChanged));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
      get { return (IEnumerable) GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // This is the DataTemplate that the consumer of your control specifies
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "ItemTemplate", typeof (DataTemplate), typeof (MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(DataTemplate)));

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
      get { return (DataTemplate) GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    // This is declared private, because it is only to be consumed by this control
    private static readonly DependencyProperty BindableItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "BindableItems", typeof (ObservableCollection<object>), typeof (MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<object>()));

    private ObservableCollection<object> BindableItems
    {
      get { return (ObservableCollection<object>) GetValue(BindableItemsProperty); }
      set { SetValue(BindableItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
      var myControl = dependencyObject as MyControl;
      if (myControl == null)
      {
        return;
      }

      // Get reference to the Grid using reflection. You could also walk the tree.
      var grid = (Grid) typeof (ItemsControl).InvokeMember("ItemsHost",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance,
        null, myControl.ItemsControl, null);

      var columns = grid.ColumnDefinitions;
      columns.Clear();
      myControl.BindableItems.Clear();

      var items = args.NewValue as IEnumerable;
      if (items != null)
      {
        var columnIndex = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
          columns.Add(new ColumnDefinition{ Width = GridLength.Auto });
          var container = new MyItem
          {
            Row = columnIndex,
            Column = columnIndex++,
            Content = item
          };
          myControl.BindableItems.Add(container);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public class MyItem
  {
    public object Content { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still confused. First, the binding will have DataTemplate on one end, but what's on the other end? Second, if the control's ItemsSource is bound to a list of strings, for example, how do I pass the each string through the template and then display it in the appropriate grid cell?

Comment: @ryan0270 I added an example for reference. Let me know if this doesn't help clear things up.

Comment: -1. You don't put a regular CLR property in a UI element. Your code is wrong. use proper DependencyProperties instead. BTW, looks like you're reinventing the `ItemsControl`. There's no need for such thing.

Comment: This is clearly labeled as an *example*, as I don't know the OP's exact use case.

Comment: I'm still confused as to how to do the layout. How can I specify that the result of applying the datatemplate to the first source item should go in cell (0,0) of the grid, the result from the second time should go in cell (0,1), etc.

Comment: @ryan0270 Will the items have properties specifying where in the `Grid` they are desired, or do you just want to keep adding them left-to-right *ad infinitum*?

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thanks for all your help, but I have one last problem. Using your code, searching for the grid inside OnItemsSourceChanged is coming up null. I tried changing to searching the visual tree, but using "int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myControl)" it shows that there are no visuals. Is it possible that the source changed event is getting called before the visuals are built?

Comment: Ok, I added a listener for the grid's Loaded event and force an update of the grid there too. This works so there seems to be timing issue with when OnItemsSourceChanged is getting called. This feels a bit hackish, though, so if you have a better method let me know. Otherwise, I can keep using this little hack :)